# eks option is not available in AWS CLI. How to install it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, aws-cli

I have installed the AWS CLI around 6 moths back and upgraded using the following command today.

`pip install --upgrade awscli`

The current version on my Ubuntu 18.04 machine is:

```
aws-cli/1.14.44 Python/3.6.5 Linux/4.15.0-23-generic botocore/1.8.48
```

When I try aws eks command, I am getting the following error:

```
Invalid choice: 'eks', maybe you meant:
    * es
```

Is my aws cli is upgraded properly or should I install something else for EKS service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to connect to the cluster from a diff aws profile. So ideally we should use the same IAM profile for running kubectl from local so that the heptio-authenticator-aws will be happy.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue on El Capitan 10.11.6 and the only one worked solution was this:

`sudo pip install awscli --ignore-installed six`

Version 6 comes with distutils in El Capitan

Reference: https://github.com/aws/aws-cli#installation

Answer (score 4):

Solutions mentioned did not resolve my issue - [this link](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-eks-ami/issues/14) helped me out in figuring the issue.

```
aws --version
```

displayed a version which was not the latest. EKS was introduced with version 1.15.32 - which means my version did not know EKS at all. Uninstalling and reinstalling did not work either, path was referring to some older version previously installed somewhere else. The solution was following installation instructions [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/installing.html) followed by [updating the path variable](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/awscli-install-linux.html#awscli-install-linux-path)

the issue cannot be resolved until the 
`aws --version`  command shows you any version less than 1.15.32.

The other solutions may be additional fixes needed afterwards, yet they will not work with an earlier version either.

Comment: Thank you - this fixed it for me, too.

Answer (score 1):

Please check with the AWS region you configured for the AWS CLI you installed.
AWS EKS is available only on US East (N. Virginia) and US West (Oregon).
Do check it properly and configure the same for AWS CLI.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue because my current aws cli version was old (as shown below)

```
$aws --version
aws-cli/1.14.44 Python/3.6.8 Linux/4.15.0-58-generic botocore/1.8.4
```

Upgrading the awscli version helped to resolve the issue

```
$pip3 install --upgrade --user awscli
$aws --version
aws-cli/1.16.252 Python/3.6.8 Linux/4.15.0-58-generic botocore/1.12.242
```

Here is the link to upgrade awscli 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-linux-al2017.html

Answer (score 0):

This happens when we install `aws-cli` using apt packages as below.

```
sudo apt-get install awscli
```

because by default it will install 1.14 `aws-cli` version. Therefore my recommendation is to use pip3 to install `aws-cli` to your machine. It always installs the latest `aws-cli` version.

```
pip3 install --upgrade --user awscli
```

Answer (score 0):

All this not worked for you then

```
pip uninstall awscli 

sudo rm -rf /usr/local/aws

pip3 install awscli --upgrade --user
```

aws --version
aws-cli/1.18.39 Python/3.6.9 Linux/4.15.0-1065-aws botocore/1.15.39

if this is older version(aws-cli/1.18.39) then it won't work for you